# Is connection from skype to skype encrypted?

Tags: skype, privacy

Is skype to skype audio and video calling secured?I mean are the connections encrypted?
And when I call from skype to skype then is it connects to any server?or the connection is Peer to Peer?If I use skype over public wifi then can anybody intercept my call?

Comment: I don't know about others, but NSA surely can :)

Comment: Actually I am not asking about NSA.I am talking about others and hackers.

Comment: http://freedom-blog.net/2009/03/ten-reasons-why-you-should-boycott-skype/ 7. Skype is Insecure -> ...Austrian government officials admitted it is easy for them to eavesdrop on Skype conversations.

Comment: And what made you think "others" are not organized groups with resources similar, or bigger than NSA? (or even hacked the NSA and got their resources). In short, encrypted yes. Peer to peer yes. Connection via server only to see if you are online, but then the actual connection are peer to peer. [Source](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10983/what-are-p2p-communications). If you use skype via public (unencrypted) wifi, people can eavesdrop your wifi connection but of course since Skype encrypt your connection so you are somewhat safe. Whether it is truly safe is a different question.

Answer (score 5):

It is, according to their support site.

> **Does Skype use encryption?**
>
> All Skype-to-Skype voice, video, file transfers and instant messages
>   are encrypted. This protects you from potential eavesdropping by
>   malicious users.
>
> If you make a call from Skype to mobile and landline phones, the part
>   of your call that takes place over the PSTN (the ordinary phone
>   network) is not encrypted.

[Source](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA31/does-skype-use-encryption)

Answer (score 0):

It may be encrypted, but it can go through Skype's servers. Now, Skype is part of Microsoft. Edward Snowden revealed (among other things) that the USA's National Security Agency (NSA) has a vast data collection program, named [PRISM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRISM_%28surveillance_program%29): In collaboration with various Internet communications companies, including Microsoft, they get copies of the communications of innumerable people, including Voice-over-IP.

So, even if someone is not actually listening in on your conversations, someone (incl. Microsoft, the US government and other parties in good standing with them) can listen in. Also it is quite conceivable that your conversations are saved somewhere and can be replayed if said parties want them. This is not certain but it's quite possible, and I would say probably considering what we've learned so far (and the fact that voice does not take up that much disk space).

So, in this sense, your Skype-to-Skype connection is **not** encrypted the way you might expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, yes, Skype connections are encrypted.

However they are definately backdoored.  You don't have the flexibility of thinking maybe its secure against PRISM, - Microsoft have specifically designed the network so anyone with a search warrant can evesdrop on it][1](https://www.bluecoat.com/security-blog/2014-01-02/exploring-encrypted-skype-conversations-clear-text).  They would claim they had to due to CALEA requirements), and they have made this fact public knowledge.

Worse then this - [In some cases its quite practical for people in the path of the traffic to decrypt it](https://www.bluecoat.com/security-blog/2014-01-02/exploring-encrypted-skype-conversations-clear-text) - particularly in the case of a typical medium - large business where system administrators routinely install stuff on the desktops (this can be things to intercept the microphone/speaker and/or inserting a trusted CA root - which is oft-times legitimate ].  Hackers who can compromise a CA and get a cert can also listen in - and this has happened in the past.